# How to show previous 3 inputs in mysql

Tags: mysql, input, show

So i make this code:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE 
`id`=(select max(`id`) from `data` 
WHERE `cat`='$data[cat]' and `id` < $data[id])
```

So... how can edit it.. to show not only one result, but the last 3 inputs from `$data[id]`

Comment: show some sample output .your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * from data WHERE 
`cat`='$data[cat]' and `id` < $data[id] 
order by id DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM `data` id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

This sql select last 3 inserted rows from 'data' table

```
SELECT * FROM `data` where  id IN ( select id from data where `cat`='$data[cat]' and `id` < $data[id])  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 3
```

The second sql for select last three rows from a particular value

Answer (score 1):

Try order by with where clause

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM `data`  
WHERE `id` < $data[id]
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

This will select down three rows whose ids less that data['id']